# Using HTML inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a div with id="upper_div". I have a script linked to my HTML page. Inside the script I have another div with id="lower_div". I want to use the div inside the script.

i.e I want to append the lower_div with upper_div. I'm not able to get the div inside the script.

```
<div id="upper_div"></div>

<script src="test.js" method="get" type="text/javascript">              
<div id="lower_div>
<p>"Test"</p>
</div>
</script>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
var html = "<div id='lower_div'><p>Test</p></div>";
$('#upper_div').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery the following will work:

```
$('div#upper_div').append('<div id="lower_div"><p>"Test"</p></div>');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qeemp/) is a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: $('#upper_div') is much faster than $('div#upper_div')